# Bootstrap modal fires multiple events from a single modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a single modal that is activated by many buttons on my page. There is an event listener on the submit button inside the modal. If I open the modal once, the event listener fires once when the "submit" button is clicked. If I open the modal 3 times, the event listener fires 3 times when the "submit" button is finally clicked.

I thought I could fix this by only setting the event listener on the submit button when the modal is actually shown, but this hasn't helped. I guess I could simply remove the event listener as soon as the modal is hidden, but I think there is a larger memory problem here that I would like to understand. Any thoughts on what's going wrong?

This is executed once DOM content has been loaded.

```
$('#edit-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event){
    var modal = $(this);
    console.log('Modal is shown');
    modal.find("#submit-modal").on('click', function(event){
        //do something with form data inside modal
        console.log("Submit Clicked");
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961853/why-im-getting-more-than-one-on-click-event-fire-inside-bootstrap-modal