# Bootstrap modal stacking data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar, bootstrap-modal

So... I'm facing a unexpected behavior in my code. I believe that it is related to bootsrtap modal.
**Code**:

```
/* Create fullcalendar.io calendar;
*  Listen to calendar event click;
*  Toggle modal, console.log a message, then close the modal;
*/

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'), {

   eventClick: function(info) {
      $("#modal").modal('toggle');
      document.getElementById("modal-submit-button").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
         $("#modal").modal('hide');
         console.log("here");
      })
    ...

   }

}
```

**Unexpected Behavior**
First #modal-submit-button click:
`console: here`
Second #modal-submit-button click:
`console: here`
`here`
`here`
Third #modal-submit-button click:
`console: here`
`here`
`here`
`here`
`here`
`here`

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961853/why-im-getting-more-than-one-on-click-event-fire-inside-bootstrap-modal

Comment: note: if i console.log(cont++) instead, the output would be: 1; 1 2; 1 2 3...

Comment: Every time you click an event, you are adding another listener to the modal. But you never remove any of the older ones. So then the subsequent clicks execute all the event listeners you've added previously as well as the latest one. That's why you see repeated output. Just define the listener once, outside fullCalendar